# onclick for <object> not working

Tags: javascript, html, object, iframe

I want to embed a web page in to my website and be able to listen for clicks on the element.

```
<object id="test" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" style="margin-top: -5px;" height="580px">Your browser sucks!</object>
```

- I have tried adding onclick to it. I have tried using .click function
  event in script.
- I have tried wrapping the `<object>` in a `<div>` but any clicks in
  the `<object>` are not seen.
- I have even used body and    window click functions - it's as if
  `<object>` element no longer exists    on my website, only clicks
  outside the `<object>` work.
- The same behaviour also happens on iframes.

Comment: The <object> element can't be clicked.

Comment: add parent div and put **onclick** on div

Comment: MJN - check my question, already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `pointer-events: none;` to your object element.

Comment: onclick still doesnt work with this but I still need the embedded website to be interactable

Answer (score 0):

What for me worked was adding `pointers-events: none;` to the style of the object.

Also tried adding a parent `<div>` container and playing around with `z-index`. Both didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used this structure to solve the click problem

```
<div class="icon">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="xxx"></object>
  <div class="click-layer" @click="alert('hello')"></div>
</div>

<style>
.icon {
  position: relative;
}
.icon .click-layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
</style>
```